# ESP32 UART receives only during step by step debugging

Tags: c, esp32, uart

I have two UARTS, embedded with two 485 tranceivers.
Both the UARTS are able to send datas trough 485 tranceivers (data enable pin is correctly cabled). I tried to send some characters from the UART1 to UART2, but seems that UART2 don't receives the sent frame. But if work with debugger and execute **uart_get_buffered_data_len** routine step by step, finally returns the number of character inside the buffer, and i can easly get the buffer with **uart_read_bytes**. Both the UART owns their task, both the tasks have the same priority.

The uarts's configurations are really similar, both are configured as follow:

UART1:

```
const int uart_num = UART_NUM_1;
uart_config_t uart_config = {
    .baud_rate = 19200,
    .data_bits = UART_DATA_8_BITS,
    .parity = UART_PARITY_DISABLE,
    .stop_bits = UART_STOP_BITS_1,
    .flow_ctrl = UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_DISABLE,
    .source_clk = UART_SCLK_DEFAULT,
};
    
// Set UART log level
esp_log_level_set(TAG, ESP_LOG_INFO);

ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Start RS485 application test and configure UART.");

// Install UART driver (we don't need an event queue here)
// In this example we don't even use a buffer for sending data.
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_driver_install(uart_num, BUF_SIZE * 2, 0, 0, NULL, 0));

// Configure UART parameters
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_param_config(uart_num, &uart_config));

ESP_LOGI(TAG, "UART set pins, mode and install driver.");

// Set UART pins as per KConfig settings
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_set_pin(uart_num, 17, 18, 8, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE));

// Set RS485 half duplex mode
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_set_mode(uart_num, UART_MODE_RS485_HALF_DUPLEX));

// Set read timeout of UART TOUT feature
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_set_rx_timeout(uart_num, ECHO_READ_TOUT));
```

UART2 configuration is the same, but changes **UART_NUM_1** to **UART_NUM_2**, and the pins (**43, 44, 21** instead **17, 18, 8**).
UART1 loop simply send a stream every second

```
printf("SEND!\r\n");
uart_write_bytes(uart_num, "CIAO\r\n", 6);
```

And UART2 loop simply checks and receive every second the buffer and print on the console

```
int length = 0;
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_get_buffered_data_len(uart_num, (size_t*)&length));
printf("RECEIVED %d bytes\r\n", length);
if (length > 0)
{
    int len = uart_read_bytes(uart_num, Uart2RxBuf, length, (100 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS));
    if (len > 0)
    {
        uint16_t i = 0;
        while (len) {
            putchar(Uart2RxBuf[i]);
            len--;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I use a loop of putchar because often (when i work step by step) UART2 receives has a 0 on the first character of the buffer (so if I use a printf it will print nothing).

I can grant that the hardware level works well (if don't, UART2 shouldn't receive anything, step by step debug or not), and I also checked the TTL stream on the UART2's RX pin.

With the micro in running, the console output is like that:

```
RECEIVED 0 bytes
SEND!
RECEIVED 0 bytes
SEND!
[...]
RECEIVED 0 bytes
SEND!
SEND!
RECEIVED 120 bytes
CIAO
CIAO
[...]
CIAO
```

But if i place a breakpoint in the **uart_get_buffered_data_len** and i execute step by step the routine, the output is like that:

```
RECEIVED 49 bytes
SEND!
CIAO
CIAO
CIAO
CIAO
CIAO
CIAO
CIAO
```

I really can't understand what is the problem... Thanks to all that will help me to resolve the problem!

Comment: How do you prevent overruns?

Comment: I don't think it's an overrun problem. If correctly handled, the core is powerful enough to sustain a transmission and a reception in the same time.